# Set layout elements in an AppCompactActivity divided into fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, appcompatactivity

An  AppCompactActivity class is linked to 3 Fragments on which you can move through the bottom menu. All the code is in the AppCompactActivity.  The app marks me an error in setting up seekbar and textview [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setMax(int)' on a null object reference].
I do not want to move the code in the java file of the respective Fragments,  is it possible to solve the problem equally?

Main Activity

```
public class OpSearchPlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

    Button get_place, bSave;
    EditText etPosition;
    SeekBar sbDistance;
    TextView tvProgress,tvLat, tvLon;
    int progress = 2;
    int maxProgress = 80;


    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    public static final String LoginPREF = "login";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_op_search_place);




        get_place = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getPlace);
        bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savePlace);
        etPosition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.position);
        sbDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbDistance);
        tvProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProgress);
        tvLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLat);
        tvLon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLon);
        sbDistance.setMax(maxProgress);

        sbDistance.setProgress(progress);
        tvProgress.setText("" + progress);

        sbDistance.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                progress = i;
                tvProgress.setText("" + progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

Layout Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dlMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ale.butastupa.OpSearchPlaceActivity">





    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav"></FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#c1c1c1"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menumap">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvMenu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/position"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="posizione attuale"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SELEZIONA PUNTO DIVERSO"
                android:id="@+id/getPlace"
                android:layout_weight="3"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/sbDistance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvProgress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>



        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CERCA"
            android:id="@+id/savePlace"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Fragment 1

```
public class FilterOpSearchFragment extends Fragment  {






    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_opsearch_filter, container, false);




        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Comment: You have a null object reference. I think your SeekBar is not instantiated. Did you get your SeekBar from your view? Should look something like this in your code :  `SeekBar simpleSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.simpleSeekBar);`

Comment: The items have been initialized


public class OpSearchPlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

    SeekBar sbDistance;
    int progress = 2;
    int maxProgress = 80;

    …


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_op_search_place);

   …

        sbDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbDistance);

        sbDistance.setMax(maxProgress);
        sbDistance.setProgress(progress);

Comment: Are you using the seekbar in any other parts of your code? As you are using your seekbar as an instance variable my guess is that you are changing some values on it before it has been instantiated in your onCreate method. It would be nice if you could include some code in your question over the usages of the SeekBar.

Comment: edited,
I added the code

Comment: Ah I see, I think you might have to add your instansiations inside your fragment class, you cant directly get them from another layout like this. Why dont you just skip having the fragment and add all components directly into your MainActivity layout. I don't think there is a simple way to get all components from a fragment to MainActivity. I just dont see the point either of having the fragment if you are going to use all components inside your MainActivity. Sorry didnt quite catch your question until I saw the code.

Comment: I posted under the solution. Thank you very much Ogiez!

Answer (score 1):

I solved. Just use the "getSystemService" functions and then "inflate". In this way

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layoutFilter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_opsearch_filter, null);

    get_place = (Button) layoutFilter.findViewById(R.id.getPlace);
    bSave = (Button) layoutFilter.findViewById(R.id.savePlace);
    sbDistance = (SeekBar) layoutFilter.findViewById(R.id.sbDistance);
    tvProgress = (TextView) layoutFilter.findViewById(R.id.tvProgress);
```

but now the bottom_menu covers the whole page